# React prop-type module map undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, select, react-proptypes

Am getting a TypeError saying property of 'map' is undefined. Just switched over to using the prop-type module with React 16 and am wondering if I have some syntax issue or an error in my code as I am not finding how I can setup my select function outside of what I have in my code. This is for a form with type of input having its own container. For the `select.js`, my code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Select = (props) => (
    <div className="form-group">
        <select
            name={props.name}
            value={props.selectedOption}
            onChange={props.controlFunc}
            className="form-select">
            <option value="">{props.placeholder}</option>
            {props.options.map(opt => {
                return (
                    <option
                        key={opt}
                        value={opt}>{opt}</option>
                );
            })}
        </select>
    </div>
);

Select.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    selectedOption: PropTypes.string,
    controlFunc: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string
};

export default Select;
```

Comment: are you passing `null` or `undefined` in your `options` array?

Answer (score 1):

Write default props for component to avoid props related exceptions

```
Select.defaultProps = {
    options: [] // keep it as empty or give some default values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting props.options to be an array, but the error is that options does not have a property of .map on it, which means it's likely not an array.

Try `console.log(props.options)` and `console.log(typeof props.options)`, the output should help you diagnose your problem.

In the case that props.option will eventually have the right data, but not at first, try `(props.options || []).map` instead of `props.options.map`.

As a side note, PropTypes doesn't affect how a React app runs, it just performs input validation on props while developing your app.